# How to insert type 0 block along with data in zlib

Tags: c, linux, header, zlib

I have to insert uncompressed data in between the compressed data bytes. Type 0 header in zlib allows me to do that. But How can i do that ? any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no type 0 allowed in a zlib header.  There is a stored block type in the deflate format used within a zlib stream.  zlib will automatically use stored blocks if they are smaller than the same data compressed.